# expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token

Tags: c

[image]Could not able to solve this..
I am implementing a queue. After writing the complete code I had the error listed below:

`expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token`

Then I wrote a simple program, but same problem persists. Couldn't able to understand how to solve this. I have looked into solutions in `stackoverflow.com and google.com` a lot but still couldn't able to solve this.Please help.

I would like to `initialize globally` `Q.front = Q.rear = Any value`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Queue
{
    int front, rear;
    int queue[10] ;
};
struct Queue Q;
Q.front = 0;
Q.rear = 0;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Q.front = 0;` is not a simple initializer, it is executable code; it cannot occur outside of a function.  Use a proper initializer for `Q`.

```
struct Queue Q = {0, 0};
```

or with named initializer syntax (not available in all compilers, and as yet only in C):

```
struct Queue Q = {.front = 0, .rear = 0};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't initialize variable using `Q.front = 0; Q.rear = 0;` in global scope. Those statements should be inside `main` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

As @Naveen said you can't assign to a member of a struct that is in global scope. Depending on the version of C though you could do this:

```
struct Queue q = {0,0};
```

or

```
struct Queue q = {.front = 0, .rear = 0 };
```