# defining struct members prior to runtime in C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a question about why we cannot define members of a struct prior to runtime in C. I have the following struct setup and ready to go:

```
struct GSM{

    char* status;
    char* make;
    char* accept;
    char* connect;
    char* exit;

};

struct GSM GSM_comms = NULL;
```

Now I am aware that I cannot define members of this struct outside of main(). However I am really interested to know why.

Is it because the struct needs to be allocated on the stack and pointed to variable data on the heap?

EDIT:

I cannot for example do this:

```
struct GSM{ 
    char* status;
    char* outbound;
    char* inbound;
    char* exit;
};

struct GSM GSM_comms;

GSM_comms.status = &variable;

int main(){

}
```

Comment: *Now I am aware that I cannot define members of this struct outside of `main()`* not true at all, and lacks context to know what you really mean.

Comment: `I cannot define members of this struct outside of main().`...wait...what? What did you just do then?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is *initialize*. The members are *defined* as soon as you say `struct x { ... };`

Comment: This question is unclear. Please clarify what you mean?.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart you can __initialize__. you _cannot use an assignment_.

Comment: I always thought define and initialise being the same thing. With declare meaning to declare without assigning value.

Comment: shouldn't it be, `struct GSM *GSM_comms = NULL;` or just `struct GSM GSM_comms;` ?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. will edit question

Comment: "Why can't I X?" is a hard question to answer when you definitely can X. Even after substituting various words in the question with other words I still don't understand what you think you can't do.

Comment: in the edit you can do it like this: `struct GSM GSM_comms = { .status = &variable };`

Comment: Thanks @Art part of that solution has been provided below, however this is also very useful.

I guess my question at this point is why we can't initialise/define using the period operator outside of int main()

Comment: So the actual question is "why can't we write code outside of the place where code should be". Because that's how the language was designed. We only run functions. One explanation of that is that when compiling a problem with multiple source files what is executed should not depend on which order the files are specified on the command line to the compiler/linker.

Comment: The only thing that is actually executed before `main` is initialization. And to keep it deterministic, initialization may not be code, just constants.

Comment: see this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310944/expected-asm-or-attribute-before-token

Comment: haha, yes I should put the code bit where the code goes... thanks again guys/girls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're using to initialize your struct is invalid.  You're trying to assign `NULL`, which is a pointer, to an instance of (not a pointer to) your struct.

To initialize a `struct`, you need to supply values for each value in the struct enclosed in curly braces:

```
struct GSM GSM_comms = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

EDIT:

The reason you can do this outside of a function:

```
GSM_comms.status = &variable;
```

Is because this is an assignment, not an initialization.  Only a definition (with an optional initializer) can appear outside of a function.  You would need to do this:

```
struct GSM GSM_comms = { &variable, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

Comment: Yeh the NULL assignment is just habit to avoid dangling pointers. 

Ah ok.. I wasn't actually trying to assign there but this notation is very helpful nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: @MedicineMan25 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: re: edit. Ok awesome. I need to be more clear with myself about the difference there. 

I assume the rules of assignment and initialization are different. Will do some more learning. Thanks again!